# Understanding a condition in Bash script "if [ $?ABC ]; then"

Tags: bash, if-statement

In a bash script I see a condition as below, which I am not able to understand, and also could not find out about it
Consider below

```
if [ $?ABC ]; then
    echo "here-a"
else
    echo "here-b"
fi
```

In above code ABC is an environment variable.
Help me understand this and/or point to relevant resources.

Comment: `[ $?ABC ]` will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: I does not look like the person who wrote this, really knew what he was doing.

Answer (score 3):

From the Bash manual about [$?](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_003f):

> Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

An "exit status" is always a number.

From the manual page of [`test`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html):

> ```
> -n STRING
>     the length of STRING is nonzero
> STRING equivalent to -n STRING
> ```

If you concatenate a number (exit status) with the string "ABC" the length of the new string will be always nonzero. As [Fravadona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591535/understanding-a-condition-in-bash-script-if-abc-then/70591851#comment124787749_70591535) told you: the result will be always true.

You can replace the five lines with:

```
echo "here-a"
```

The `else` expression has no effect.